# idiom -Manolito,Manolito..?

Tags: modismos

I recently listened to an episode of the podcast''Hoy Hablamos''. I cannot find the episode number but there was a phrase I didn't catch.

The meaning of it was something along the lines of meddling in something you know nothing about and making the situation worse.

It may have started like''Manolito,Manolito,...el toreo...para que te metas...''.I presume it was an idiom but may have been lines of a song or some other cultural reference.
I believe it may be Spanish as the podcaster is from Galicia.
I am curious as it may be a nice one to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ay, Manolete, Manolete... Si no sabes torear pa (para) que te metes

It's a popular saying: if you don't know something, if you don't know how to do something, it's better to stay out of it or keep quiet.

This is usually said to the person who has stuck his nose where it doesn't belong.

Comment: ¿Popular? Qué raro, jamás en mi vida escuché una frase como ésta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Me frustra cuando no puedo acceder a algo que escucho de paso.

Comment: Manolete, es un nombre,verdad?

Comment: Si, diminutivo de Manuel o Manolo. Hay un torero famoso ya muerto, [Manolete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manolete_(film)), cuyo film biográfico lo protagonizaron Adrien Brody y Penélope Cruz.

Comment: @tac El refranero español es muy rico, estoy seguro que hay muchas frases como esta que jamás has escuchado.

Comment: @Danielillo aa no sé no sé. "No es 'español universal' así que no vale" xd

Comment: Los refranes son miles, hay muchos que yo tampoco conozco. El de *Manolete...* es muy habitual en España

Comment: Por extender un poco en la respuesta. "Manolete" es un diminutivo del nombre Manuel, y era el nombre "artístico" de un torero muy famoso que falleció a consecuencia de una cogida por parte de un toro (de nombre Avispado). Años después de su muerte comenzó a utilizarse esta frase con el significado que Danielillo ha indicado, haciendo ver que, si Manolete hubiera sabido torear mejor, probablemente no hubiera sufrido la cogida que acabó con su vida. Curiosamente, Manolete estaba considerado como un gran torero.